# Unable to overwrite decorator pattern method

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I'm learning Decorator pattern and I couldn't wrap my brain around the method overwriting.

I have a `Phone.ts` class that has `phoneDescription` and `cost` getter.
The cost getter should be overwritten with the cost of the phone brand class that extends to it.

**Phone.ts**

```
export default class Phone {
  private description: string;

  constructor(description = 'Default description') {
    this.description = description;
  }

  get phoneDescription() {
    return this.description;
  }

  get price(): number | void {
    throw new Error('This method must be overwritten!');
  }
}
```

I have a model-specific class. In this example, Pixel.

**Pixel.ts**

```
import Phone from './Phone';

export default class Pixel extends Phone {
  get cost(): number {
    return 800;
  }
}
```

So far so good. I am able to instantiate the `Pixel` class.
And I'm able to get the the cost from the object.

**PhoneDecorator.ts**

```
import Phone from './Phone';

export default class PhoneDecorator extends Phone {}
```

But phone screens are pretty fragile. We need a screen protector.
So,

**ScreenProtector.ts**

```
import PhoneDecorator from './PhoneDecorator';

export default class ScreenProtector extends PhoneDecorator {
  phone: any;

  constructor(phone: any) {
    super();
    this.phone = phone
  }

  get cost(): number {
    return 50 + this.phone.price;
  }
}
```

This screen protector should add **50** to the current price of the phone supplied in the constructor.

But I'm getting the error `This method must be overwritten!`

**index.ts**

```
import ScreenProtector from './ScreenProtector';
import Pixel from './Pixel';

let pixel = new Pixel();

pixel = new ScreenProtector(pixel);

console.log(pixel.cost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cost` is a method of your decorator, not phone. So you need to implement `price` getter of `Pixel` (not `cost`):

```
export default class Pixel extends Phone {
  get price(): number {
    return 800;
  }
}
```